# JRun Servlet Error "The system cannot find the path specified" when attempting to upload multipart form

Tags: forms, coldfusion, upload, multipartform-data, jrun

Some code a production server which uploaded files has seemingly stopped working with the following error:

`JRun Servlet Error` as the title of the page and the following in the page body:

```
500

The system cannot find the path specified


java.io.IOException: The system cannot find the path specified
at java.io.WinNTFileSystem.createFileExclusively(Native Method)
at java.io.File.checkAndCreate(File.java:1704)
at java.io.File.createTempFile(File.java:1793)
at coldfusion.filter.FormScope.fillForm(FormScope.java:231)
at coldfusion.filter.FusionContext.SymTab_initForRequest(FusionContext.java:437)
at coldfusion.filter.GlobalsFilter.invoke(GlobalsFilter.java:33)
at coldfusion.filter.DatasourceFilter.invoke(DatasourceFilter.java:22)
at coldfusion.filter.RequestThrottleFilter.invoke(RequestThrottleFilter.java:126)
at coldfusion.CfmServlet.service(CfmServlet.java:175)
at coldfusion.bootstrap.BootstrapServlet.service(BootstrapServlet.java:89)
at jrun.servlet.FilterChain.doFilter(FilterChain.java:86)
at coldfusion.monitor.event.MonitoringServletFilter.doFilter(MonitoringServletFilter.java:42)
at coldfusion.bootstrap.BootstrapFilter.doFilter(BootstrapFilter.java:46)
at jrun.servlet.FilterChain.doFilter(FilterChain.java:94)
at jrun.servlet.FilterChain.service(FilterChain.java:101)
at jrun.servlet.ServletInvoker.invoke(ServletInvoker.java:106)
at jrun.servlet.JRunInvokerChain.invokeNext(JRunInvokerChain.java:42)
at jrun.servlet.JRunRequestDispatcher.invoke(JRunRequestDispatcher.java:286)
at jrun.servlet.ServletEngineService.dispatch(ServletEngineService.java:543)
at jrun.servlet.jrpp.JRunProxyService.invokeRunnable(JRunProxyService.java:203)
at jrunx.scheduler.ThreadPool$DownstreamMetrics.invokeRunnable(ThreadPool.java:320)
at jrunx.scheduler.ThreadPool$ThreadThrottle.invokeRunnable(ThreadPool.java:428)
at jrunx.scheduler.ThreadPool$UpstreamMetrics.invokeRunnable(ThreadPool.java:266)
at jrunx.scheduler.WorkerThread.run(WorkerThread.java:66)
```

This issue is reproducible with the following code and occurs when the form is submitted.

```
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="test.cfm">
    <input type="FILE" name="frmFile">
    <input type="submit" name="frmSubmit" value="Upload">
</form>
```

Does any one have any ideas about what might have triggered this issue, how to resolve it and how to prevent it happening in the future?

Kind regards,

Tom

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After finding very little useful information elsewhere I tried restarting the Coldfusion service and this resolved the issue.

However, I'd still be interested if anyone has any idea what may have caused this in the first place.

Comment: Do you have caching enabled of templates?   Could be something wrong there and it cached a temporary file path that is no longer there.  Seems a long shot but possibly plausible explanation.   Look and see in the log files if you got any errors for the test.cfm before the service stopped working.